# iOS SSKeyChain and Login Check

Tags: ios, ios7

I got the SSKeyChain working and tested that what is retrieved is same as what was previously stored. I am conducting all of this in the login action when user presses the button. I want to know if what I am doing is correct or not (illustrated in steps below):

- User launches application for first time, landing page has creating account or logging in.
- User provides logging in credentials and presses the button
- In the body of the action, I take the parameters query database (HTTP) and if response is valid, user proceeds. If not, user requested to re-enter credentials.
- Once and if user login successfully, I will use SSKeyChain to store his credentials (**but what use are these credentials for me in the future?**)

What I am really asking is: what is the use of SSKeyChain in above scenario? Also if the user login successfully, where am I going to store his credentials (is it via SSKeyChain) so that next time he will skip the login screen (like facebook, twitter apps).